# Git stating there are local changes while there aren't

Tags: git

I use git for deployment on the live server, I made a commit, pushed to the repo on BitBucket and then made a git pull from the server.

Since then I'm unable to make any "pull" at the live server, I keep getting this message:

`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        www/js/khalid.js
 Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.`

although there aren't any local changes that I've made.

I tried `git reset --hard` and `git checkout file_name` also `git stash` and nothing works.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `git commit` to complete the merge, since you are in the middle of the merge, I suppose

Comment: I ran git commit and found conflicts, fixed them. Committed. and then pull. Everything now works. However I still wonder what made the file change on the server!